# Is there any way to delete the URL address whenever a user enters my website?

Tags: html, url

I have a website which I want to hide its URL the second a user enters it.

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: I don't think there's a way.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to set up fraud website. I hope there is no such option…

Comment: did you looking for a permanent redirect ?

Comment: Hopefully not else it would make phishing even easier...

Comment: I don't think there's a way to completely remove it but you can definitely alter it to some extent. Like remove the hashes, or shorten the link or use a proxy or add and remove various other symbols to it.

Comment: @feeela I'm working on an A/B testing website for statistics, and just think that it would look more aesthetic that way..

Comment: @saru95 that might be helpful, what key words should I google?

Comment: Try removing hashes using .htaccess, or writing a url shortener, . Just google whatever I mentioned above. It'll be pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is done server-side. You cannot change the url of the site with let's say javascript or php. If you write your .htaccess file to point to that url, or rename the url of your site on the server to change what the user is hitting is the way to do that.

You can check [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049) for the .htacccess way of doing it.